# Solve 'merge' between different repos

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm looking for some help due the structure of a product development which I inherited. We have two repositories **A(Private, for development purposes)** and **B(Client repository, with some branches)** but one of the problem is that repositories aren't the same structure but have the same files and with this in mind, this is the problem I encountered:

**Repo A** -> Unlimited quantity of commits when develop a functionality

**Repo B** -> The main idea is to keep as reduced commits as possible

**Ex**: I made 6 commits on A but need to push those changes to Repo B in only one single commit, is there any possibility to handle this by Git or do I need to continue to copy+paste manually?

PS: I'm using sourcetree if this helps

Comment: I love VonC's solution. But @Jose, is `git rebase` really not applicable in your case?

Comment: @artoodetoo It isn't since there are more members of the team working on the sames repos

Answer (score 2):

copy+paste is easier, except you can ask Git to do it for you, in command line (not in SourceTree)

```
cd /path/to/local/clone/B
git --work-tree=/path/to/local/clone/A add .
git commit -m "import A state"
git push
```

You reference A as a work tree: B will detect any file added/modified/deleted since the last commit of B.